# Condições em Javascript

Tags: javascript, if

Descobri recentemente que é possível que é possível guardar o resultado de uma condição (como de um `if`) em uma variável:

```
var x = (1 > 2); // false
var y = (2 > 1); // true
```

Vejam no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ym9z/

- Como se chama esse recurso?
- Pra que serve/quando é útil?
- Também está disponível em outras linguagens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Expressões

Normalmente chamamos `+`, `-` `*` etc de **operadores matemáticos**, `<`, `>`, `==` de **operadores condicionais**, ou de comparação, e `and`, `or`, ou `&&`, `||` e similares de **operadores boolianos** <sup>1</sup>.

Um conjunto de valores, permeados por operadores, é o que chamamos de "expressão", e uma expressão retorna um valor.

## A "Expressão Condicional"

A condição não tem nada de especial, pois como dito, o `>` é apenas um operador. E o `if` simplesmente usa seu resultado para definir o que fará.

Quando você diz:

```
if (x > y) { ...
```

Está primeiro calculando o valor de `x > y`. Vamos supor que por acaso `x` realmente seja maior que `y`, o resultado deste "cálculo" será o valor `true`, portanto teria o mesmo efeito como se estivesse escrito `if (true)` naquele caso em específico.

Da mesma forma, `if (x > y)` é equivalente a:

```
var meu_teste = x > y; // teste recebe o valor true se x > y

if ( meu_teste ) { ...
```

Só depois de "calculado" o valor de `x > y` que o `if` usará o resultado retornado. Na verdade o `if` "não fica nem sabendo, tampouco se importa" com o que aconteceu dentro dos parênteses.

## A "Expressão Booliana" <sup>1</sup>

Da mesma forma, `or` e `and` também poderiam ser guardados em var" ;)

```
var condicoes = true or false; // true || false, etc.
if ( condicoes ) { ...
```

> Em resumo: você está apenas guardando um valor de uma operação como qualquer outro. Assim como `a + b`, as operações `a > b`, `a || b` e `a++` retornam um valor ao final.

<sub>1. Grafada como Booleana em muitos lugares, porém confirmei no VOLP que na nossa língua é com "i"</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Isto está disponível em outras linguagens também...

O Grande diferencial é que em JavaScript você não precisar especificar o tipo da sua variável, ou seja, não precisa informar se ela é um Boolean, String, Interger ou coisa do tipo.

A sua operação **`(1 > 2)`** retorna um valor booleano (**false** neste caso ) por isto consegue atribuir este valor à sua variável **x**.

Em Java por exemplo vc vai precisar dizer que sua variável vai receber um Boolean para realizar esta operação.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean x = (1 > 2);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Em php tem algo parecido também, mas olha só.

```
$x = (3 > 1);
$y = (1 > 2);

var_dump($x); //boolean true
var_dump($y); //boolean false

echo $x; //1
echo $y; //(imprime nada)
```

Porém isto não é nenhum recurso especial, ao utilizar um operador de comparação, o resultado sempre vai ser um booleano.

Comment: Isso é por causa da conversão de boolean para string que o php faz no `echo`.

Comment: O ideal seria o PHP converter o booleano `false` para string `"0"`, não? Se o valor fosse `null` ai sim ele não deveria imprimir nada.

Comment: Verdade, seria um bug?